# How can I distribute a Catalyst Application?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, ipados

how can i distribute a Catalyst app? The app supports: `iOS`, `iPadOS` and `macOS`. What should i select in AppStore Connect for creating a new app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Xcode as Apple recently changed how Mac Catalyst apps are given bundle IDs without needing separate apps in App Store Connect. When creating a new app on App Store Connect, click on "new app", and select iOS and macOS. iPadOS and watchOS apps fall under the category of iOS. [image]

Comment: will i need to select the same build for iOS and macOS when i upload the app to appstore connect

Comment: You will need to upload multiple builds. One for macOS and one for iOS/iPadOS.